# Adding Listener to a method inside a class in Java

Tags: java, swt, listener

I am having a hard time implementing a listener to a method.

I have a method `fillTableRoWData()` that creates a table. The method is called inside two if conditions simultaneously.

I have stored all of my values in a hahMap.

The problem is when I update the combobox value: only the value in the second condition is updated.

I want to add a Listener that tells the method which if condition is updated and add the data at the relevant hashMap position.

Also When I enter the data into any TableColoumn the data should be updated in the HashMap

```
package view;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TableShellExample {

    Display d;

    Shell s;

    Table table;
    private Text text_1, text_2, text_3, text_4;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> list2 = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> list3 = new HashMap<>();
    private static Integer a = 0;
    private static Integer q = 0;

    TableShellExample() {
        d = new Display();
        s = new Shell(d);

        s.setSize(250, 200);

        s.setText("A Table Shell Example");


        Table table = new Table(s, SWT.BORDER);

        String[] titles = { "Theart Name", "Category", "Satus", "Priority",
                "Description", "Justification" };
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setWidth(150);
            column.setText(titles[i]);
        }

        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        fillRows("1","2","3");



        s.open();
        while (!s.isDisposed()) {
            if (!d.readAndDispatch())
                d.sleep();
        }
        d.dispose();
    }


    private void fillRows(String shortdesc, String categ, String descp) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);

        // for Threat_Name
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);

        text_1 = new Text(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_1, item, 0);
        text_1.setText(shortdesc);
        // list2.put(a++, text_1.getText());
        System.out.println(a + " : " + list2);

        // For Category_Name
        //editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_2 = new Text(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_2, item, 1);
        text_2.setText(categ);
        // list2.put(a++, text_2.getText());
        System.out.println(a + " : " + list2);

        // For Status_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        final Combo Status_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        Status_Combo.add("Mitigated");
        Status_Combo.add("Not Applicable");
        Status_Combo.add("Not Started");
        Status_Combo.add("Needs Investigation");
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(Status_Combo, item, 2);

        Status_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(Status_Combo.getText());
            }
        });

        // For Priority_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        final Combo priority_Combo = new Combo(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        priority_Combo.add("High");
        priority_Combo.add("Medium");
        priority_Combo.add("Low");
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(priority_Combo, item, 3);

        priority_Combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(priority_Combo.getText());
            }
        });

        // For Descrption_Name
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_3 = new Text(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_3, item, 4);
        text_3.setText(descp);
        // list2.put(a++, text_3.getText());
        System.out.println(a + " : " + list2);

        System.out.println(list3);

        // For justification
        editor = new TableEditor(table);
        text_4 = new Text(table, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor(text_4, item, 5);

        list3.put(q++, new HashMap() {
            {
                put(a, text_1.getText());
                put((a + 1), text_2.getText());
                put((a + 2), text_3.getText());
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new TableShellExample();
    }

}
```

Comment: Down-votes with no explanations are not helpful.  
They can also discourage new users asking and seeking help or advice.
I think that down voting question of new users should be avoided as much as possible. 
For those I recommend the opposite : explanation without down-voting.

Comment: This is a rather long code, and I am not sure I understood what's the problem. Consider posting [MCVE]  to demonstrate the problem, and make it easier to help you.

Comment: I have edited the code. What I want is if I change the value in comboBox than it should be updated in the hashmap value also @c0der

Comment: It is very hard to help you as it is. Please read carefully [MCVE]. Make it MINIMAL ("Create a new program, adding in only what is needed"). Make it COMPLETE with all classes and imports needed to run it.

Comment: @c0der I have a very big project with connected files. So not able to put everything here. What I want is some kind of listeners that calls on my fillrows method in IF conition so that the data in hashmap is updated when I select different values in combobox.

Comment: The idea is not to "put everything here" but "Create a new program, adding in only what is needed" . A small / short code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @c0der I have generalized the code and given the exact output that I need . Can you take a look at it and hepl me. This is the best general code that I can provide at the moment. Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: @S.Mehta The code you provided doesn't even compile. Please make sure that it does. People are unlikely to go through your code and figure out how to make it compile only to then go through your code again to figure out what's wrong. Also, it should be self-contained, i.e. so that people can just run it. Include a `main` method.

Comment: Sorry, I really tried but I don't know how to help you if I can't run it. You must make the effort need to post an [MCVE]. If it is too complex break it down and cope with one problem at a time.

Comment: @c0der  I have implemented a running example of what I want to do. Maybe now you can look at it. The problem is still the same I want to add the combobox values to the Hashmap at the respective key positions

Comment: @S.Mehta Please only use the "code snippet" feature for actual JavaScript/CSS/Other web stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look into using a `TableViewer` with `EditingSupport`. By doing that, you don't need to keep track of the selected values, they'll be stored in your bean class. Here's a very simple example that shows a table with one combo box column where you can select from two values:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * @author Sebastian Raubach
 */
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("StackOverflow");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        createMasterPart(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.setSize(400, 300);
        shell.open();

        shell.layout(true, true);

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createMasterPart(Composite parentComposite)
    {
        Composite composite = new Composite(parentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite tableComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        TableColumnLayout tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
        tableComposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
        tableComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(tableComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        TableColumn tableColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
        tableColumn.setText("Sample");
        tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element)
            {
                Dummy p = (Dummy) element;
                return p.getValue();
            }
        });

        tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent selectionChangedEvent)
            {
                StructuredSelection selection = (StructuredSelection) selectionChangedEvent.getSelection();

                System.out.println(((Dummy) selection.getFirstElement()).getValue());
            }
        });

        List<Dummy> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            elements.add(new Dummy("First option"));
        }

        tableViewer.setInput(elements);

        tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(tableColumn, new ColumnWeightData(1, true));

            /* Set the editing support here */
        tableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport(new FirstValueEditingSupport(tableViewer));
    }

    private static class Dummy
    {
        public String value;

        public Dummy(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static class FirstValueEditingSupport extends EditingSupport
    {

        private final TableViewer viewer;
        private final CellEditor  editor;

        private final String[] possibleValues = {"First option", "Second option"};

        public FirstValueEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer)
        {
            super(viewer);
            this.viewer = viewer;
            this.editor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(viewer.getTable(), possibleValues);
        }

        @Override
        protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)
        {
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEdit(Object element)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getValue(Object element)
        {
            Dummy dummy = (Dummy) element;

            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++)
            {
                if (Objects.equals(possibleValues[i], dummy.getValue()))
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        @Override
        protected void setValue(Object element, Object value)
        {
            Dummy dummy = (Dummy) element;

            int index = (Integer) value;

            dummy.setValue(possibleValues[index]);

            viewer.update(element, null);
        }
    }
}
```

It'll print the current selection when you select an item.